# Finding the convergence radius of $\dfrac{(n!)^k\cdot x^n}{(kn)!}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If K is a integer positive, find the convergence radius of the series  $$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(n!)^k\cdot x^n}{(kn)!}$$

Any initial idea?

Comment: use ratio test.

Comment: Try using the formula $R=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}$.

Comment: Note that $(kn)! \ge (n!)^k (k!)^n$; so the radius of convergence is at least $k!$.

Comment: @AnuragA using the ratio test I find: lim n->inf (n+1)^k*x / k(n+1)!, and got stuck, maybe I did something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ratio test gives
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{(n+1)^k\cdot x}{(kn+k)(kn+k-1)\dotsb (kn+1)}\right|&=\left|\frac{n^k(1+1/n)^k\cdot x}{n^k(k+k/n)(k+(k-1)/n)\dotsb (k+1/n)}\right|
\end{align*}
As $n \to \infty$ this ratio approaches $\left|\dfrac{x}{k^k}\right|$. For convergence you need this limit to be less than $1$, hence the radius is $k^k$.

Comment: Hm almost got there haha, now I see, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ratio test or the root test in combination with Stirling's approximation. I will demonstrate the latter:

$$\sqrt[n]{(n!)^k} \sim_\infty \Big(\frac{n}{e}\Big)^k, \,\, \sqrt[n]{(kn)!} \sim_\infty \Big(\frac{kn}{e}\Big)^k$$ so that $$\sqrt[n]{ \frac{(n!)^k}{(kn)!} } \sim_\infty \big(\frac{n}{e}\frac{e}{kn}\big)^k = \frac{1}{k^k} = \frac{1}{R} \iff R = k^k.$$